# Add files to iTunes playlist

Tags: applescript, itunes

Sorry if it has already discussed but I'm unable to find an answer.

I would like to add files from a choosen folder to an existing iTunes' playlist.
I don't want to copy/duplicate these files (so iTunes would create a new folder inside its Music folder).

If I use:

```
add myFolder to playlist playListName
```

songs are duplicated in a new "Music" folder

If I use:

```
add myFile to playlist playListName
```

I have a type error, something about «class cUsP» id 20647 of «class cSrc» id 66 of application "iTunes".

My app code contains several subroutines, not easy to understand unless I post the entire code.

myFolder can be defined by dropping a folder onto the app, or by command choose folder.
Then, playListName is extracted from the choosen folder's pathname.

Then, folder is processed like this, in order to create playlist:

```
on processFolder(thisFolder, playListName)
    tell application "iTunes"
        activate
        -------------------------------- create playlist
        try
            set newPlaylist to (make new user playlist with properties {name:playListName})
            set view of browser window 1 to newPlaylist
        on error errMsg
            beep
            my dlog("Unable to create playlist " & my kwote(playListName) & "." & return & return & errMsg, {"Abort"}, appTitle, "error")
            return false
        end try
        --***add thisFolder to newPlaylist -- create new "Music folder" and duplicate files !!!

        --------------- add files --> tracks
        tell application "Finder"
            repeat with thisFile in (get every file of folder thisFolder)
                if (my isValidFile(thisFile)) then
                    tell application "iTunes"
                        try
                            add thisFile to playlist playListName -- ERROR !!!
                        on error errMsg
                            beep
                            my dlog("Unable to add file " & my kwote(thisFile as text) & "." & return & return & errMsg, {"Abort"}, appTitle, "error")
                            return false
                        end try
                    end tell
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell

        return true
    end tell
end processFolder

on isValidFile(thisFile)
    tell application "Finder"
        set the fileInfo to (info for thisFile as alias)
        if (mp3Check) then
            if (alias of the fileInfo is false) and ((the file type of the fileInfo is in the typesList) or (the name extension of the fileInfo is in the extensionsList)) then return true
        else
            if (alias of the fileInfo is false) then return true
        end if
        return false
    end tell
end isValidFile
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more example code, i.e, how you constructed the myFolder & myFile variables. Make it easy for us to replicate an help.

Comment: My app code contains several subroutines, not easy to understand unless I post the entire code. I just edited original post to paste main subroutine.

Comment: Just tried "add (thisFile as alias) to playlist playListName --> no error but file is duplicated into a new "Music" folder :(

Comment: Fixed. My question was irrelevant: iTunes settings was modified so it copies new files in its Media folder. So **add myFolder to playlist playListName** is working fine.